# limit of supremums

Tags: real-analysis

define $\limsup s_n = \limsup \{s_n : n > N\}$

i'm trying to figure out why lim sup $s_n^2 = (\limsup s_n)^2$ is false but lim sup $s_n^3 = (\limsup s_n)^3$ is true. can anyone give me a nudge in the right direction?

Comment: Squaring does funny things to signs.

Comment: If we have a sequence that alternates between positive and negative terms, the lim sup might be a smaller number than if we squared everything and then took the lim sup of the sequence (since there could have been a very large negative number that turned positive)?. Is this intuition sound?

Comment: @user147103 : Why do you write \$s_n\$\$^2\$ instead of \$s_n^2\$?  The latter gives you $s_n^2$ and is standard usage.  That and several other aspects of your MathJax usage just look like making things unduly complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Let $s_n = -2$ if $n$ is even, and $s_n = 0$ if $n$ is odd. Then calculate each of the above.

Comment: (lim sup s_n)^2 is is 0 but lim sup(s_n)^2 is 2?

Comment: and if it were cubed the signs would be preserved, which is why it would still hold true?

Comment: Except $(-2)^2=4$ the last time I checked.